# Change title of navigationItem Title based on selected Tab Bar Item

Tags: iphone, ios

[image]I have a Tab Bar View Controller that has four possible view controllers. My main tab bar view that all the other views have a relationship too has a navigation bar that i can double click on and change the title in my storyboard. What i need to know is how to changed the title of this navigation item based on the selected tab bar item.

For instance i will have four tabs. 1 is "Bills", 2 is "Groceries", 3 is "Gas", and 4 is "Personal". I want the title of my view to be Bills if the "Bills Tab is selected and so on.

EDIT:  Hopefully this will clarify what i'm trying to accomplish.

I want to be able to change the title of the Navigation Bar at the top of each of the four table Views on the right. The Tab Bar Controller is the only place that I can actually double click and change the tile while is storyboard.  I want the title to change based on which table view is selected from the tab bar.

Comment: Are the "four possible view controllers" each an instance of the same class? Is this where you're wanting to change the title? Or are you wanting to change the title of say a parent view controller?

Comment: each of the table view controllers with have their own class even through it will be almost the same just loading a different datasource.

Answer (score 2):

Remove any navigation bar item you manually added to the view controller and add this to your `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"My Title";
```

or

```
self.navigationController.topViewController.title = @"My Title";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to set the title property within each of the "four view controllers" like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Title For View Controller Goes Here";
}
```

Then, whenever said tab for this view controller is clicked, the navigation bar's title should change to this title.

**Edit**

It sounds like you may have placed a `UINavigationBar` object from Interface Builder in your tab bar's view. Instead, you actually want to have the `UITabBarController` embedded within a `UINavigationController`.

Go through Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on starting storyboarding, and this should show you how to do this:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Good luck!

Comment: This is what i figured I needed to do just wasn't 100% sure of the steps. The whole protocol and delegate thing is still a little confusing to me. The part where you say I need to pass in a "child reference", does that get put in my partent class?

Comment: Thats what i thought but for some it doesn't work. During debug it hits the line of code and i can see that _title has been changed but it doesn't show up. I think it has to do with the fact that each of those four table view controllers don't actually have a navigation item. The only place that my Navigation Item actually exists is at the Tab Bar Controller. The four table view controllers don't actually have a selectable navigation Item in storyboard.

Comment: Have you written code for the four table view controllers creating navigation items?  If so, could you post it?  If not, you need to create navigation items, either with code or in the storyboard--I can explain how to do that if you need it.

Comment: @Joe - My navigations Items are all created through the use of storyboards.

Comment: @JRG - i believe that is how i did it. If i change the top bar option in simulated metrics  from inferred to none and run i still have the Navigation bar in my tab bar controller even though it doesn't show up in the storyboard. And if I create a custom class for the tab bar controller i can set the title to what ever i want. It just won't changed when i select a new tab. Even if i have done a  `self.title = @"Some Name";` in the back end associated with the selected view controller.

Answer (score 1):

On every tab selection you can change title.

```
   - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
     didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
      viewController.title=@"your title"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I should warn you that this method may be an inelegant hack, because I'm only just beginning to understand navigation myself.  But here's how I would approach it:

Basically, you should add a `UINavigationItem` to each of the `UIViewController`s you want to have a title, and change the text of the `UINavigationItem` depending on which `UIViewController` is showing.